# Can't run python scripts in lldb

Tags: python, fedora, lldb

I'm trying to run some python inside of lldb. When I execute the script command, I get the following error:

```
(lldb) script
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lldb.embedded_interpreter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_python_interpreter' is not defined
```

I'm using lldb version 4.0.1 and Python version 2.7.13 on Fedora 26

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you. If you want to post as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sometimes it's the easy things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `python-lldb` installed for this to work. `sudo dnf install python-lldb` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have python-lldb installed. Unfortunately yum cannot search in repositories that are not currently configured on the machine. Even if the repository containing the desired module is already configured on the machine, it's not always easy to find the module in the list of available modules produced by "yum list available". So to find how to install python-lldb for your Linux distro/version, search online for the keywords: search yum repositories online. From the search results, select an online packages search website (I used https://pkgs.org). Search for "python-lldb" and select the package info page for the distro/version (CentOS 7 in my case). Use the repository name to add the repository if necessary (in my case the repository "CentOS SCLo RH x86_64 Official" was already present). Use the package name with whatever package manager you are using (yum in my case) to install. For me, the command I ended up using was "sudo yum install -y llvm-toolset-7-python-lldb".